AccessToken lifetime should be different for UI users and API clients
I'm using authorization code flow to login UI users and client credentials to login API clients.
AccessToken lifetime should be few minutes for UI users but few hours for API clients.
I'm using SetAccessTokenLifetime method in
services.AddOpenIddictCoreWithEntityFramework()
            .AddServer(options =>
            {
                options.SetAccessTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(accessTokenLifetimeInMinutes));
              options.SetRefreshTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(refreshTokenLifetimeInMinutes));
}

How to specify different AccessTokenLifetime for UI users and API clients?
No any packages could help

Just use
var clientCredentialsClaimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(clientCredentialsIdentity);

clientCredentialsClaimsPrincipal.SetAccessTokenLifetime()

in the Token endpoint where claims principal for clientCredentials flow login are created
